# ubuntu 18 simple scan no detect scanner cannner lide300 please help

Tags: scanner

Install Canon LiDE 300 / 400 on Ubuntu 18.04 how to fix it please help me pls

[image: Simple Scan]

Comment: Help with what? You need to give details of what you have done, what is wrong and how you have tried to fix what ever is wrong. As asked there can be no help.

Comment: There is an insufficient amount of information here to offer a solution. Could you [edit] your question to include: (1) how the scanner is connected (USB/Network/SCSI/etc.) (2) whether you have [installed the drivers from Canon](https://en.canon-cna.com/support/consumer_products/products/scanners/lide_series/canoscan-lide-300.html?type=drivers&language=en&os=linux%20(64-bit)) or not. With this, it may be possible to offer a solution 

Comment: I connect Canon LiDE 300 (USB) to my ubuntu I need to use simple scan to scan but it cannot find scan machine

last six month I ever can used. I try use this command line

sudo apt install libsane-common
 sudo apt install sane-utils 
sudo apt install xsane

 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rolfbensch/sane-git
 sudo apt-get update

But now those command can't use. (current I setup new OS Ubuntu18.04)
@matigo

Comment: @KDB You have but one answer. You do not make any comment on it. In fact, you appear to have ignored it. In what way is it not suitable?

Answer (score 0):

The LiDE 300 is supported by [sane-airscan](https://github.com/alexpevzner/sane-airscan). Get a Debian binary from [here](https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/pzz/xUbuntu_18.04/amd64/). You will need **ipp-usb** from the same place too.